# Xcode: Apple Mach-O Linker Error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386

Tags: xcode

This is my code. While Running this, I get the below error.,,

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Reachability", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in ASKViewController.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

```
-(void) checknetork{

    Reachability *reach=[Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"http://www.google.com.sg"];
    NetworkStatus netstatus=[reach currentReachabilityStatus];
    bool net;
    switch (netstatus)
    {
        case NotReachable:
            net=NO;
            break;
        case ReachableViaWiFi:
            net=YES;
            break;
        case ReachableViaWWAN:
            net=YES;
            break;
    }

    if (net)
    {
        HUD.labelText=@"Connecting.,,";
        HUD.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
        HUD.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
        [HUD hide:YES afterDelay:2];
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert.!" message:@"Check Your Network Connection.!" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select target go to build phases select compile sources  click on + and select rechability.m you are sorted